# r dygraph plot not correctly displayed in right to left Shiny app

Tags: css, r, shiny, right-to-left, dygraphs

I have made a shiny app in Persian language which the Shiny admin css has been changed completely to rtl direction. I have only a problem with my dygraph plot which not displayed correctly. My screenshots are shown below. As you can see, when I inspect the part which is not displayed on the correct place and then I change text-align from left to right in element.style{}, everything will be OK. But how can I change the css for this element.style? This is a div within my plot1 div! I tried many ways to change the css but it didn't work. Moreover in the css file of dygraph I changed all of left-aligns to right but it didn't work too. Thanks in advance for any comment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please consider adding some [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve fixed as many RTL issues as I can in Dygraph 2.2.0 so please upgrade to that version. If there are still any left afterwards, please provide an MVCE so that they can be fixed; it’s hard for people who don’t normally use an RTL environment.

https://dygraphs.com/tests/rtl.html works (I’m not sure if you’d flip the axis label or something…) and most things can be done using just CSS now.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts for fixing rtl issues. At the moment this is not further my issue because it was my problem for a long time ago. But I will check the new version and if there was any issue I'l send feedbacks.